# Wordpress php Plugin not found

Tags: php, wordpress, function, callback

I am getting this Warning and my Header and Footer on my Website are not showing them right.

> Warning: `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function `'remove_admin_bar_style_frontend'` not found or invalid function name in `/home/toolsebo/www/yr-1007/wp-includes/plugin.php` on line 496

I tried to find the `remove_admin_bar_style_frontend` in my **functions.php** to remove it but i cant.

Please help me to get this fixed i really don't know how to go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp-includes/plugin.php is a core file, it wouldn't be in there, that's just what's generating the error.

Look in your **wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/** folder for a functions.php or similar file.  The function will be in there.

Comment: Thanks! I was not looking at the Themes Folder and now i found it there, so its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are calling the function "remove_admin_bar_style_frontend" but that function was not in your plugin or theme. Search for that initiating code block and comment it.Try to search add_action('....